# Creating a chq database in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have made a spreadsheet for printing on business cheques.  I was hoping transfer the information into another sheet which will list all of the chq's I have printed. Ideally, I would like the information to transfer, when I hit Ctrl+Q (which I use to print the chq).  I know the easiest way to copy information is ='chq tracking'!K23 , but that wouldn't work, as it would only show the most current chq.
Is there a way to do this?  I am an average excel user so go easy on me please!
Thank-you for your time.

Comment: You'll probably need some VBA to get this done. Essentially, before you print, the code will need to determine the last row of the log and store that in a variable, then copy whatever important bits you want to keep from the 'chq tracking' tab to the Log's last row. I can't think of any ready-built excel functionality that automagically logs things. That would be cool though.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) this would go something like this:

```
Sub MacroCopyCurrentCheque()
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Map2").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Map1").Activate
End Sub
```

It is not possible to be more specific without more input from your side. (Excel version, how do you print exactly, with a macro? Worksheet names? Do you know how to use VBA, etc)